# Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Tags: vba, excel

I can't post an image so I wanted to explain my question in more detail.

I have 2 files: The vlookup formulas are in the Destination File. The vlookup values are in the Source File. The Destination File will be closed. The Source File will be opened. In the Source File, I may change 15 cell values. If so, I want the 15 cells in the Destination File (closed workbook) to be highlighted yellow as they contain the vlookups when I open it. I hope this explains what we're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

> Instead of highlighting the cells, do you know how to insert a comment in each cell whenever the cell value changes? I would like to comment to say, "Changed cell from 20 to 30".

Try this code (may be time consuming for big ranges with formulas):

**in Code module (standart module):**

```
Public cVals As New Dictionary

Sub populateDict()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("CP:CV"))
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With
End Sub
```

**in ThisWorkbook module:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Call populateDict
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**in Sheet module:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngToColor As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'get only used part of the sheet
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Me.Range("CP:CV"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitHere ' if there is no formulas in CP:CV - exit from sub

    'reset color for all cells
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    For Each c In rng
        'check if previous value of this cell not equal to current value
        If cVals(c.Address) <> c.Text Then
            'if so (they're not equal), remember this cell
            c.ClearComments
            c.AddComment Text:="Changed value from '" & cVals(c.Address) & "' to '" & c.Text & "'"
        End If
        'store current value of cell in dictionary (with key=cell address)
        cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
    Next c

ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Note that I'm uisng `Dictionary` object. For working with `Dictionary` object you should add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. Go to *Tools->References* and select `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to build something similar to a trading platform to highlight cells linked with RTD formulas. If it is true (or even if you make changes manually), you can achieve your goal by using worksheet_change.

The below procedure looks at cells in columns 12 to 15 (the real-time values that change) and it compares the values in the FmlaRng (which I assume is a fixed range) before the calculate occurs and after. It is important you set your sheet as xlCalculateManual otherwise Excel will calculate the new values before you can record the old ones.

Also, I am not sure if you need to keep the Application.EnableEvents, but I left it there.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim endrow As Long, startrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim PreValue As Variant
Dim FmlaRng As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Target.Column >= 12 And Target.Column <= 15 Then 'This is where the cell initally changes (the lookupvalue cells)
    On Error GoTo 0
    startrow = 1
    endrow = 1000
    With Workbooks("Workbook2").sheets("Sheet1") 'You need to change these names
    Set FmlaRng = .Range(.Cells(startrow, 94), .Cells(endrow, 100)) 'FmlaRng is where the lookups should be
    FmlaRng.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    PreValue = FmlaRng
    Calculate 'This is when vlookups update
    For i = LBound(PreValue, 1) To UBound(PreValue, 1)
        For j = LBound(PreValue, 2) To UBound(PreValue, 2)
            If FmlaRng.Cells(i, j) = PreValue(i, j) Then
            Else
                FmlaRng.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    End with
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. I edited the code so that it looks at the lookup values in another workbook. You will need to change the names. 2. The 2 For loops, loops through every cell in the range, meaning it will highlight all cells that change one at a time (but when it finishes, all the cells that change will be hightlighted). 2. To keep all highlights, just remove the line where it says ColorIndex = 0.

Comment: @user3473205 if a solution is not correct, then leave them a comment on their post, not [defacing their post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4593985).