# excel vba on cell change error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Range = Range("A1") Then
    If Range("A1").Value <> Range("A2").Value Then
        Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
        Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

that's the code however when i copy paste a set off cell, let's say 2 columns and 3 rows
it produce runtime error 13 type mismatch on line

```
If Target.Range = Range("A1") Then
```

why?
i simply wants the vba to do something everytime cell A1 changes
the value of A1 itself is an excel sum formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get type-missmatch error, becase you're trying to compare *range (containing many cells)* with *single cell*. If you want to do something every time cell `A1` changed, use this one instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("A1").Value <> Range("A2").Value Then
            Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
            Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
        End If
    End If

ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

also note that I'm using `Application.EnableEvents = False` - it's a good habbit for `Worksheet_Change` event to use it. It prevents code from infinity firing itself each time you change any cell *in event handler code*.

**UPD:**

Btw, `the value of A1 itself is an excel sum formula` - you can't track changes of *formula* using above approach. I covered in details how you can do it in this question: [Using Worksheet_Calculate event for tracking changes of formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717269/private-sub-worksheet-calculate/22771167#22771167)

Answer (score 1):

Simoco's answer should work for you. Another way (the one I usually use, though only out of habit) is to compare the addresses:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
    If Range("A1").Value <> Range("A2").Value Then
        Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
        Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it's not working, since OP said that `i copy paste a set off cell, let's say 2 columns and 3 rows`, in that case `Target.Address` would be something like this: `$A$1:$B$3`, which obviously not equal `$A$1`

Comment: Obviously. Your reading of what he's doing may be different to my reading of it but my reading is that he wants this to fire ONLY when he makes a change that affects the formula in A1 by itself (hence the equals statement in the original code) and not when he makes a change which may INCLUDE A1. I could be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because Target.Range is not defined. You should either just refer to Target (a Range Object) or Target.Address (the address of the Range Object). Secondly, depending on the context, Range("A1") refers to either the cell A1 itself (a Range Object) or the value in cell A1 (a literal value). You need to carefully think what you want to compare to what.

If, as you said, you want the comparison done whenever the value in Range("A1") changes then you should follow Simoco's suggestion.