# VBA event fired by sheet recalculation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a VBA method to fire an event in excel from a sheet recalculation.  The following code only works when the cell is manually entered.  I need the event to fire after a specific cell recalculates.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = Range("numcase").Address Then
        Dim Diagram As String
        numcase = Range("numcase").Value
        Diagram = numcase & "case"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(Diagram).ZOrder (msoBringToFront)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no such built-in event. Look here for possible background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717269/private-sub-worksheet-calculate/22771167#22771167

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` will fire, but there's no way to target a specific range: you would have to track changes in the range's value if you want to trap only certain changes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround that I have used before to trap a change to a filtered list will also work

- Add a *dummy sheet*
- In a cell in this *dummy sheet*, add a formula such as `=SUBTOTAL(103,Sheet1!A1:A10)` where this range is your `numcase` range
- Add this code to the sheet code (*Right Click Sheet Tab .... View Code ... Paste*)
- Update the code to do what you need

*code*

```
'Dummy sheet code
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'Your range has been changed
    MsgBox "Your range has been changed"
' rest of your code from above
End Sub
```